# charts.js global options gridLines

Tags: chart.js

I'm using the Charts.js API and I can not configure the global options.
For example, I do not want to display vertical lines; for a chart:

```
scales: {
 xAxes: [{
   gridLines: {
    display: false
   }
```

}]
    }

How to make global options?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.display = false` ?

Comment: This also works for setting gridlines color globally, for example: `Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = 'rgba(255,255,255,.1)';`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a transparent color for the grid lines:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    gridLines: { color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' },
    ...
  }],
  ...
}
```

Comment: While this may be a possible answer to the question. Apart from code examples you should give some context around it explaining how does it fix the OPs problem.